# get data from server Backbone.js application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

**Update: I am updating the question with the answer of  Sushanth --, I have faced some troubles prevent the code from run successfully [the latest update of my code in the question below after this quote "Latest Update" & the issues below it]**

I am developing an Backbone.js application and I am stuck with getting data from the server.

```
http://localhost:8888/client/i/schedule
```

This url represents json array of the required data, the problem here is how could i make the view read this data from the collections and model

There is 3 files below:

**The first one is for the view**

```
// Filename: views/schedule
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'collections/schedule',
'text!templates/schedule.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, scheduleCollection, scheduleTemplate) {

var scheduleView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $(".app"),
    initialize: function() {},

    render: function() {             
        console.log('schedule view loaded successfully');
    }
});
return new scheduleView;
});
```

**The second one is for the collection**

```
// Filename: collections/schedule
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/schedule'
], function($, _, Backbone, ScheduleModel){
  var ScheduleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ScheduleModel,
    initialize: function(){
        console.log('schedule collections loaded successfully');
    }
  });
  return new ScheduleCollection;
});
```

the first one is for the model

```
// Filename: models/schedule
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'config'
], function(_, Backbone, config) {
var ScheduleModel = Backbone.Model.extend({    
    urlRoot: "http://localhost:8888/client/i/schedule",    
    defaults: {
      feedback: 'N/A'
    },
    initialize: function(){
        console.log('schedule model loaded successfully');
    }
  });
  return ScheduleModel;

});
```

**Update**

The router

```
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            // Define some URL routes
            'schedule': 'scheduleRoute',
            // Default
            '*actions': 'defaultRoute'
        },
        scheduleRoute: function() {

            scheduleView.render();
        },

)}
```

**Latest Update**

**The router.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',    
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'app/views/dashboard',
    'app/views/schedule'
], function($, _, Backbone, dashboardView, scheduleView) {
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            // Define some URL routes
            'schedule': 'scheduleRoute',
            // Default
            '*actions': 'defaultRoute'
        },
        scheduleRoute: function() {
            // Create a new instance of the collection
            // You need to set the url in the collection as well to hit the server
            var schedules = new Schedules();
            // Pass in the collection as the view expects it
            var scheduleView = new ScheduleView({
                collection: schedules
            });
           // No need of calling render here
           // as the render is hooked up to the reset event on collection          
        },
        defaultRoute: function(actions) {            
            // We have no matching route, lets display the home page
            dashboardView.render();
        }
    });

    var initialize = function() {                
        var app_router = new AppRouter;
        Backbone.history.start();
    };
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

**The schedule view .js**

```
// Filename: views/schedule
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'app/collections/schedule',
    'text!templates/schedule.html'
], function ($, _, Backbone, scheduleCollection, scheduleTemplate) {

    var scheduleView = Backbone.View.extend({
        collection: scheduleCollection,
        el: $(".app"),
        initialize: function () {
            // Listen to the reset event which would call render
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
            // Fetch the collection that will populate the collection
            // with the response 
            this.collection.fetch();
        },
        render: function () {
            console.log('schedule view loaded successfully');  
            console.log(this.collection);
        }
    });
    return new scheduleView;
});
```

**The collection**

```
// Filename: collections/schedule
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'app/models/schedule'
], function ($, _, Backbone, ScheduleModel) {
    var ScheduleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ScheduleModel,
        url: "http://sam-client:8888/sam-client/i/schedule",
        initialize: function () {
            console.log('schedule collections loaded successfully');
        }
    });
    return ScheduleCollection;
});
```

**The schedule Model**

```
// Filename: models/schedule
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'app/config'], function (_, Backbone, config) {
    var ScheduleModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        // If you have any
        //idAttribute : 'someId'
        // You can leave this as is if you set the idAttribute
        // which would be apprnded directly to the url
        urlRoot: "http://sam-client:8888/sam-client/i/schedule",
        defaults: {
            feedback: 'N/A'
        },
        initialize: function () {
            console.log('schedule model loaded successfully');
        }
    });
    return ScheduleModel;

});
```

**Issue**
code not run as expected and console log me the error below

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_listenerId' of undefined
```

**Update**
the answer was that i miss to return a value from the ScheduleView.js

[Backbone.js is not a constructor error when create instance of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427927/backbone-js-is-not-a-constructor-error-when-create-instance-of-view/18428006?noredirect=1#18428006)

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to  listen to the `reset` event on the collection for the view in question.

Then use fetch to send in the request.

```
var scheduleView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $(".app"),
    initialize: function() {
       // Listen to the reset event which would call render
       this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
       // Fetch the collection that will populate the collection
       // with the response 
       this.collection.fetch();
    },
    render: function() {             
        console.log('schedule view loaded successfully');
        console.log(this.collection)
    }
});
```

And to reduce the confusion return the Backbone View,Model or Collection instead of a new Instance from the module.

So when you define the module, you can create a new instance.

```
// Filename: views/schedule
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'collections/schedule',
    'text!templates/schedule.html'], function ($, _, Backbone, scheduleCollection, scheduleTemplate) {

    var scheduleView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $(".app"),
        initialize: function () {},

        render: function () {
            console.log('schedule view loaded successfully');
        }
    });
    return scheduleView;
    // Remove the returning of new module here
});
```

And in the module where you want to add the view as the dependency

```
// Create a new instance of the collection
// You need to set the url in the collection as well to hit the server
var schedules = new Schedules();

// Pass in the collection as the view expects it
var scheduleView = new ScheduleView({
    collection : 
})
```

**UPDATE**

**model**

```
// Filename: models/schedule
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'config'], function (_, Backbone, config) {
    var ScheduleModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        // If you have any
        //idAttribute : 'someId'
        // You can leave this as is if you set the idAttribute
        // which would be apprnded directly to the url
        urlRoot: "http://localhost:8888/client/i/schedule",
        defaults: {
            feedback: 'N/A'
        },
        initialize: function () {
            console.log('schedule model loaded successfully');
        }
    });
    return ScheduleModel;

});
```

**collection**

```
// Filename: collections/schedule
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/schedule'], function ($, _, Backbone, ScheduleModel) {
    var ScheduleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ScheduleModel,
        url: "http://localhost:8888/client/i/schedule",
        initialize: function () {
            console.log('schedule collections loaded successfully');
        }
    });
    return ScheduleCollection;
});
```

**view**

```
// Filename: views/schedule
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'collections/schedule',
    'text!templates/schedule.html'], function ($, _, Backbone, scheduleCollection, scheduleTemplate) {

    var scheduleView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $(".app"),
        initialize: function () {
            // Listen to the reset event which would call render
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
            // Fetch the collection that will populate the collection
            // with the response 
            this.collection.fetch();
        },
        render: function () {
            console.log('schedule view loaded successfully');
            console.log(this.collection)
        }
    });
});
```

In some other module,

you would require the the views, that you want to render

**Router**

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        // Define some URL routes
        'schedule': 'scheduleRoute',
        // Default
        '*actions': 'defaultRoute'
    },
    scheduleRoute: function () {
        // Create a new instance of the collection
        // You need to set the url in the collection as well to hit the server
        var schedules = new Schedules();
        // Pass in the collection as the view expects it
        var scheduleView = new ScheduleView({
            collection: schedules
        });
       // No need of calling render here
       // as the render is hooked up to the reset event on collection 
    }
});
```

Comment: Possibly `set` instead of `reset`, depending on the Backbone version, so you'd want to listen for `add/remove/change` too.

Comment: @loganfsmyth.. right, it depends on the event the user wants to listen to.

Comment: @Sushanth-- I am a bit confusing as I am a new user of backbone.js, so could you please give me a full view of the three files and where to put the url

Comment: sure.. What exactly does `"http://localhost:8888/client/i/schedule"` respond with.. Is it an array of objects or just a single object.. Cause you have defined it inside the model

Comment: it's an array of objects

Comment: What is the rest end point for a single object that will be in the model.. And does each model has a id attribute on it

Comment: i miss something regarding this block of code placed after this "In some other module", where to put it in the application

Comment: it depends on where you want to insert or initialize the view

Comment: view initialized via router, I updated the question, please check it :)

Comment: @Sushanth-- I am facing some trouble, the question was updated with the full page structure please review